# Potentiometer ADC noise varies based on position of wiper?

Tags: stm32, adc, noise, signal-to-noise

I have a potentiometer setup as a voltage divider like so, where the wiper of the potentiometer gets fed into my MCUs ADC Pin:

[image]

When I measure the noise of the incoming ADC signal, I get different levels of noise based on the position of the wiper.

For example, I get greater noise when the voltage is closer to 3.3V, and much less noise when the voltage is closer to GND.

I can't understand why this might happen . The noise is reaching levels that are quite problematic as well...

The way I am determining signal noise it by taking 100 samples of the ADC while the potentiometer is "idle" (ie. not being touched) and then calculating the noise of the signal by determining the highest value sample recorded minus the lowest value sample recorded divided by 2. Here are some rough values being logged.

```
Wiper position close to 3.3V rail:   noise around 1000
Wiper @ middle position:             noise around 500
Wiper position close to GND:         noise is minimal (around 40)
```

So yeah... signal noise is increasing as the voltage on the ADC pin increases. This couldn't be a faulty potentiometer could it?

Comment: I’d suggest checking your wiring - especially your gnd. Where exactly does it connect to? Ground is not necessarily ground!  Are you reading the correct adc input? Reading the one next door can give strange results simply due to capacitive coupling.

Comment: There is inherently nothing wrong with the schematic you show. However, there might be problems in the schematic parts you don't show, or the code you don't show, or the physical realization of the circuit you don't show, or the pot might be old and oxidized or low quality factory rejects you bought from a shady online store, which we also don't know, or just built on a breadboard. Edit the question to have enough relevant info for a solution.

Comment: It could just be noise on the 3.3V supply line. Try increasing the capacitor to a much larger value - eg 100uF or putting filter before (or after) the pot. Or use a battery for an experiment.

Comment: How many bits of result is that? Having 4000 counts of noise would be almost full scale range for a 12-bit ADC. Also is your sampling time settable, and is it too short? Which MCU is this?

Comment: @Justme its technically a 12-bit ADC (stm32f446re), but I do a bitshift so I can deal with 16-bit values. So (uint16_t)1000 is approx 1 / 65th of the ADC range, which is really quite poor when you think of it. Since I have to account for this maximum amount of noise, that leaves me with a resolution of like... 4 or 5 bits?

Comment: I think that is too much noise to explain only by having a switching regulator, but good thing you have it solved now.

Comment: NB: if one uses the supply voltage as "reference", noise can also be added by this supply.

Comment: @Antonio51 yeah I guess I never really looked at it like a reference voltage, as it powers my analog ICs - but I am def using it as one

Comment: @Kartman could you expand on ground not necessarily being ground?   I am revisiting this and have a feeling my pot is going lower the 0V, which is causing problems on my ADC pin.

Comment: Wiring has resistance. Depending on the current flowing through the wire you get a voltage drop. In the case of your gnd wiring, all points may not be at the same voltage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the noise is the switching regulator and switching logic loads on it.

As the potentiometer wiper is moved closer to the supply rail, the resistance between the rail noise and the capacitor is lower. So the cut-off frequency of the RC filter is higher and has less effect as seen at your sampling rate.

As the wiper is moved further from the rail, the RC filter has a lower cut-off frequency.

The filter cut-off frequency is given by: fc = 1/(2 x Pi x RC)

To alleviate this, you can put the supply through an initial RC filter before driving the potentiometer. The below circuit uses a filter with an fc of 72 Hz, far below your rail supply/load switching frequencies. The 100 ohm series resistor drops just under 1% of the 3.3 V rail so the potentiometer still has almost the full range. With the noise removed, the potentiometer will give a much truer range anyway.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUE2kW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit removes the capacitor on the potentiometer output as it's not needed. You don't give part numbers so the ADC input impedance is unknown. But it must have a high input impedance for you not to see worse noise at the mid-ish rail pot' settings.

Comment: Power supply ripple would still get scaled by the voltage divider, even without a changing RC filter in the loop. I wonder what's the relative contribution of the two mechanisms.